# Postcode disappearing when batch updating country

Tags: addresses, upgrade

I am batch updating the country of 700 records that have become countryless. I need the country to make sure the geoding works.

I initially used a profile with just the country/longtitude/latitude  on but when I updated my records (which only had an postcode in the address) the postcode disappeared. I suspect the whole address field is being updated not just the country.

When I include the postcode in the update profile the postcode remains after the country field update.

So I have a work around BUT I feel I may be missing something quite important about the way address fields work together.

Can anyone explain?

Thanks
Caroline

Comment: Ouch. Can you replicate this on dmaster.demo.civicrm.org - if so it should be reported as a bug imo